# Selecting all first element of a nested list / array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following nested list.

```
 peaks = [[313, 0.7608371709999999], [695, 0.6970320329999999], [996, 0.652950446], [1367, 0.570015382], [1518, 0.516312078], [1726, 0.5599991639999999], [1871, 0.5025837670000001], [2084, 0.563103466], [2240, 0.5229157010000001], [2478, 0.611383482], [2622, 0.59167585], [2987, 0.68685803], [3225, 0.524618916], [3573, 0.738796993], [3938, 0.8191861140000001], [4302, 0.82872904], [4666, 0.814913208], [5038, 0.7919655170000001], [5397, 0.773237498], [5762, 0.78905603]]
```

I want to extract the first element to a separate list/array and the second to another list/array.

I have done this using a for loop,

```
max_peaksIdx = []
max_peaksVal = []
for i in max_peaks:
    max_peaksIdx.append(i[0])
    max_peaksVal.append(i[1])

#out : max_peaksIsdx : [313, 695, 996, 1367, 1518, 1726, 1871, 2084, 2240, 2478, 2622, 2987, 3225, 3573, 3938, 4302, 4666, 5038, 5397, 5762]
#out: maxpeaksVal :[0.7608371709999999, 0.6970320329999999, 0.652950446, 0.570015382, 0.516312078, 0.5599991639999999, 0.5025837670000001, 0.563103466, 0.5229157010000001, 0.611383482, 0.59167585, 0.68685803, 0.524618916, 0.738796993, 0.8191861140000001, 0.82872904, 0.814913208, 0.7919655170000001, 0.773237498, 0.78905603]
```

I am curious to know if the same result can be obtained using numpy slicing? (**without** using a for loop)

something like,

```
max_peaksIdx = peaks[:][0]  #this doesn't work, just picks the first element. but get a similar result shown above, but with one line code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` with unpacking:

```
max_peaksIdx, max_peaksVal = zip(*peaks)
```

Output:

```
max_peaksIdx
# (313, 695, 996, ...)
max_peaksVal
# (0.7608371709999999, 0.6970320329999999, 0.652950446,...)
```

If you *have* to construct `numpy` array:

```
arr = np.array(peaks)
max_peaksIdx, max_peaksVal = arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1]
```

But `zip` is about 9x faster:

```
%timeit max_peaksIdx, max_peaksVal = zip(*peaks)
# 1.19 µs ± 91.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
arr = np.array(peaks)
max_peaksIdx, max_peaksVal = arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1]
# 10 µs ± 120 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Amazin. Thanks definitely what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done!

```
import numpy as np

peaks = np.array(peaks)

max_peaksIsdx = peaks[:,0]
max_peaksVal = peaks[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do so. Firstly, you can try `zip` and `unpacking` as

```
lis = []
for i in range(len(peaks[0])):
    lis.append(list(list(zip(*peaks))[i]) )
```

This will output `lis` as

```
[[313,
  695,
  996,
  1367,
  1518,
  1726,
  1871,
  2084,
  2240,
  2478,
  2622,
  2987,
  3225,
  3573,
  3938,
  4302,
  4666,
  5038,
  5397,
  5762],
 [0.7608371709999999,
  0.6970320329999999,
  0.652950446,
  0.570015382,
  0.516312078,
  0.5599991639999999,
  0.5025837670000001,
  0.563103466,
  0.5229157010000001,
  0.611383482,
  0.59167585,
  0.68685803,
  0.524618916,
  0.738796993,
  0.8191861140000001,
  0.82872904,
  0.814913208,
  0.7919655170000001,
  0.773237498,
  0.78905603]]
```

Only zip can also be used.

```
list( map(itemgetter(i), peaks))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   max_peaksIdx = peaks[:][0]
```

can also be done as

```
   max_peaksIdx = peaks[0] #stores the first element in peaks
   max_peaksVal = peaks[1] #stores the second element in peaks
```

without the ":", all without the for loop.

Comment: Sorry this wouldnt work. It just picks the first element. i.e [313, 0.7608371709999999]

Comment: it picks the first element to the first list created and the 2nd element to the 2nd list created, just going off your question. this should work without the for loop and is not a slicing approach :)